# Spring: Static bean declared inside another bean does not get initialized on Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a simple Spring boot application with following classes:

**Class A**, it has the Class B declared as a bean with a **static method**:

```
public class ClassA {
    private String something;

    public ClassA(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Class A initialized! " + something);
    }

    @Bean
    public static ClassB classB() {
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

**Class B**:

```
public class ClassB {
    @PostConstruct
    protected void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Class B initialized!");
    }
}
```

and the entry point of my **Spring Boot application class**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My problem is, I want to get both `ClassA` and `ClassB` beans created, by only defining ClassA explicitly as bean. If I do this with an XML configuration such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="com.mypackage.ClassA">
        <constructor-arg name="something" value="Hello from XML Config!"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and import it on `Application` class using `@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")` Spring creates class A and processes `@Bean` annotation on class A and creates an instance of class B. Program output is:

```
Class A initialized! Hello from XML Config!
Class B initialized!
```

But when I try to do the same thing using Java configuration, defining bean of A in `Application` class as follows:

```
@Bean
public ClassA classA() {
    return new ClassA("Hello from Java Config!");
}
```

Then an instance of B does not get created, so the program output is:

```
Class A initialized! Hello from Java Config!
```

My question is, how can I get the same behavior of XML configuration with Java configuration.

Note: I tried `@Import(ClassA.class)` on application configuration but it failed after creating the bean of B because it tried to create an instance but A does not have a **default constructor**.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The thing is, in my case ClassA and ClassB are coming from an external dependency so I cannot touch them. I can only change my configuration and what I am trying is to switch from old XML config to the full Java configuration.

Comment: Since the method is static, can you call it in your Application class with the '@Bean` Annotation, e.g.   `@Bean
    public static ClassA.ClassB classB() {
        return new ClassA.ClassB();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

An option is aggregate:

```
 @Bean
 public ClassB classB() {
    return ClassA.classB();
 }
```

At the end of your Application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA() {
        return new ClassA("Hello from Java Config!");
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB() {
        return ClassA.classB();
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Class A initialized! Hello from Java Config!
Class B initialized!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring Class B with the [discouraged lite mode.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts) Use `@Configuration`.